# Cannot Understand this code functionality

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.CheatActivity">
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/answer_text_view"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="24dp"
  tools:text="Answer"/>
```

I am a novice in programming. I started with Big Nerd Ranch programming book. I came across this code. In the book it is stated as:

> "This namespace allows you to override any attribute on a widget for the
>   purpose of displaying it differently in the Android Studio preview. Since TextView has a text attribute,
>   you can provide a literal dummy value for it to help you know what it will look like at runtime. The
>   value “Answer” will never show up in the real app. Handy!"

What does that actually mean? I am completely new. I know this is foolish question, please help me in this.

Comment: Get another book. One that is geared towards beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tools` is basically a collection of extra properties you can add to your `TextView` that assist you when designing layouts in Android Studio. In this particular example, `tools:text` allows you to put a fake value into your `TextView` which will only show up in the the layout preview in Android Studio.

This will allow you to see what a `TextView` looks like when designing your layout in Android Studio, but you don't have to worry about removing that dummy text from your layout when you build a "real" version of your app for a phone.

See also: [Tools Attribute Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html)

Comment: No worries. If any of these three answers have helped you, please upvote them and accept the answer that has helped you best.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to that line

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

you can use in all your XML something like that

```
tools:text="Answer"
```

Thanks to that line

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

you can use in all your XML element the android attribute, for example

```
android:id="@+id/answer_text_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24dp"
```

The book you're reading is a good book, keep continue and don't give up!